# How does the FBI supply NZT for Brian?

Tags: limitless

In the new *Limitless* TV series, the FBI provides NZT pills for Brian.  In the movie, at the end of it, it was revealed that Morra monopolized the production of NZT and created a serum/injection that made the user immune to the side-effects of NZT.

In the series, Brian gets NZT pills from the FBI and from Morra (because he is a double-layered agent) and Morra provides him the serum.

How does the FBI provide the pills? Does the Bureau make them (it's illegal to produce drugs)?

Comment: Amazon Prime...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that, in the real world, [research scientists can request illegal drugs for testing](http://gizmodo.com/heres-what-scientists-do-when-they-need-illegal-drugs-f-1679610944), which are created by contract labs in North Carolina and Mississippi, I would be very surprised if the FBI couldn't make a similar request. The scientists have to request a license for having and using these drugs from the DEA (Drug Enforcement Agency). Given the usual bureaucratic territorial squabbles, the FBI would probably have to similarly request a license, but I suspect they'd be able to with a moderate amount of paperwork.

Comment: +1 Also, I haven't seen any official explanation from the writers. This is the best yet.

Comment: There is no evidence that anyone but the senator knows the full formula for NZT, and he keeps it very much on the downlow that he has this knowledge. So I find it impossible to believe that the FBI could simply request it.

Answer (score 2):

In the first episode, Naz gives the back story on the FBI's involvement with NZT.  She mentions in passing that the FBI has reverse engineered the drug.  The implication is that they are able to manufacture it in house, or out of house (she does not specify.)

Brian Finch is the first opportunity they've had to actually continue tests with the drug, as he is "immune" to the side effects.